# What is a simple way to set the background cell color for a CustomGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, background

I've got:

```
<CustomControl:GridControl ShowCustomGridLines="True" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="txbCaption" Text="{Binding Caption}" />
            <CustomControl:GridControl ShowCustomGridLines="True" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="П" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Ф" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Yellow" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="%" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </CustomControl:GridControl>
```

I want to set the cell background of a TextBox (where Background="Yellow"). Setting the background for a TextBox doesn't help because I need to set the background color for the whole cell, even if there is no text.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can put some type of panel in that area and set its background color. For example:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Black" IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively put a border in the cell, then whatever control required within the border setting the background colour property of the border.

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF3C3C3F">
     <TextBlock>Some Text</TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 6):

To set the background color for an entire row or column, add this in the row or column definition:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="SomeColor"/>
```

Where you specify your cell by row + column insertion.
Then you can insert your textbox wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

WPF grid doesn't know what a "cell" is. Put a panel in there and set its color.